# Why i can't get query result in php?

Tags: php, sql

I tried to execute sql query:

```
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordpress2','root','');
    $sql = 'SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN field_id = 1 THEN  value
    END as Name,
    CASE
        WHEN field_id = 3 THEN  value
    END as X,
    CASE
        WHEN field_id = 2 THEN  value
    END as Y
    FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data';


    $rs = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
        exit;
    }
    while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $properties = $row;
        ?>
        <script> console.log("<?php $row["Name"] ?>")</script>
        <?php
    }
```

But in browser console i see only empty rows. In `phpMyAdmin` query works and return some rows.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an "echo" in `<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>`

Comment: "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." Please vote to close instead of answering.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have an entity-attribute-value data structure, within one row per value in a field.  If so, then you need an aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 THEN value END) as Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 3 THEN value END) as X,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN value END) as Y
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data;
```

It is quite likely that you also need `WHERE <something> = <something>` or a `GROUP BY`.